# Disable InjectMappingFiledId Task

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, crashlytics, gradle-kotlin-dsl

build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    getByName("debug") {
        manifestPlaceholders = mapOf("crashlyticsCollectionEnabled" to "false")
        ext["enableCrashlytics"] = false
        ...
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="${crashlyticsCollectionEnabled}" />
```

Build Analyzer still complains about:
[image]

If I add this:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
   tasks.withType<com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.tasks.InjectMappingFileIdTask> {
        enabled = ext["enableCrashlytics"] as Boolean
    }
}
```

It works, but is it the right way or a hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears you're trying to use ext.enableCrashlytics instead of firebaseCrashlytics.mappingFileUploadEnabled = false , which will prevent the resource file from being rewritten each time. The new plugin being released tomorrow has an improved UP-TO-DATE check for that task.

Relevant docs for the extension property: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android

Comment: Hi Oleg thanks for your answer. You first link throws 404 can you fix it?

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. I realized that's actually a private repo. However, updating the plugin should confirm the above info.

Comment: `Fixed the UP-TO-DATE check for the mapping file ID injection task. The task will now be correctly marked UP-TO-DATE if the mapping file ID is not modified.`
This is the fix you're talking about right?